# Create ZIP file in memory using any node module

Tags: node.js, stream, zip

Is there any node module to create zip in memory?(I don't want to save zip file on disk) so that we can send this created zip file to other server(From memory). What is the best way to do this?
Here is my example:

```
var file_system = require('fs');
var archiver = require('archiver');
var dirToCompress = 'directoryToZIP';

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
var archive = archiver.create('zip', {});
archive.on('error', function (err) {
    throw err;
});

    var output = file_system.createWriteStream('/testDir/myZip.zip',{flags:'a'});//I don't want this line
    output.on('close', function () {
        console.log(archive.pointer() + ' total bytes');
        console.log('archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed.');
    });

    archive.pipe(output);

    archive.directory(dirToCompress);

    archive.finalize();

};
```

Comment: I suggest using [archiver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver) and pipe the stream to response, this way you will not have to write anything to disk.

Comment: Here Output variable will be api of other server so that we can send this zip file.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using [Adm-Zip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adm-zip):

```
// create archive
var zip = new AdmZip();

// add in-memory file
var content = "inner content of the file";
zip.addFile("test.txt", Buffer.alloc(content.length, content), "entry comment goes here");

// add file
zip.addLocalFile("/home/me/some_picture.png");

// get in-memory zip
var willSendthis = zip.toBuffer();
```

Answer (score 3):

If GZip will do, you can use [the built-in `zlib` module](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html) and not even have to load an external module.

```js
const gzip = zlib.createGzip();

// If you have an inputStream and an outputStream:

inputStream.pipe(gzip).pipe(outputStream);
```

For Zip and not GZip, you can check out [archiver](https://archiverjs.com/docs/) or [zip-stream](https://archiverjs.com/zip-stream/).